# Where can i find development documentation for sage saleslogix 7.5

Tags: saleslogix

Some link, some PDF or something that can point me to the right direction looking understanding this CRM. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what kind of slx development you want to start with. Slx fat Client (Script or .NET) or on the Slx Web Platform (Web Client, Support Portal etc.).
Anyway a **very** good starting point is the slxdeveloper.com forum and their articles:
http://www.slxdeveloper.com

Second I can recommend the blogs of CustomerFX: http://customerfx.com/pages/
Especially Ryan Farleys (master of slx development) posts a great.

The official developer documentation was behind a customer login page of Sage. After Sage sold Saleslogix some months ago I don't know where you can get them now.